# Object moment on the screen issue - pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to stop my object from going off the screen when using the arrow keys. I managed to stop it from going out to the left and right of the screen, but when I applied the same logic for the top and bottom it didn't work. Could you advice please?

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_folder, "Zero Position.png")).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH /2, HEIGTH / 2)
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = - 10
            if self.rect.left == 10:
                self.speedx = 0
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 10
            if self.rect.right == WIDTH - 10:
                self.speedx = 0
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = - 10
            if self.rect.top == 10:
                self.speedy = 0
        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = 10
            if self.rect.bottom == HEIGTH - 50:
                self.speedy = 0

        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
```

Comment: Make sure to check before you post that everything is properly formatted. Also, always specify what _"doesn't work"_ means. Do you get errors? Does your character go pass the top/bottom? Is the character not moving at all? The code you've provided looks fine. Try to create a [mcve], and we'll probably be able to help resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The character stops at left and right but for some reason go off the top and bottom game window

Comment: better use `<=` and `>=` instead of `==`. If it has position `19` and next it will have  `9` then `9 == 10` will not stop it but `9 <= 10` will stop it. You can even move it back to position `10` when it has position `9`

Answer (score 0):

Better use `<=` and `>=` instead of `==`.

If it has (accidently) position `19` and next it will move to `9` then `9 == 10` will not stop it but `9 <= 10` will stop it.

You can even move it back to position `10` when it has position `9`

```
    if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.speedx = - 10
        if self.rect.left <= 10:  # <= instead of ==
            self.rect.left = 10:  # move it back
            self.speedx = 0

    if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.speedx = 10
        if self.rect.right >= WIDTH - 10:  # >= instead of ==
            self.rect.right = WIDTH - 10:  # move it back
            self.speedx = 0

    if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
        self.speedy = - 10
        if self.rect.top <= 10:  # <= instead of ==
            self.rect.top = 10:  # move it back
            self.speedy = 0

    if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        self.speedy = 10
        if self.rect.bottom >= HEIGTH - 50:  # >= instead of ==
            self.rect.bottom = HEIGTH - 50:  # move it back
            self.speedy = 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much furas. Your suggestion worked and fully explained my problem.